# Cinnamon panel - task list doesn't take up all available space

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-environment

I'm running Cinnamon on Arch Linux. For some reason, the system tray seems to be taking up half the available panel space, forcing the taskbar part of the panel to start shrinking the buttons even though there should be plenty of space left.

Anyone know how to configure it so that doesn't happen?

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you sure that's the system tray's fault? Could you have added something else to the panel that's blank but taking up space? I don't see this on my Arch, Cinnamon 3.0.7

Comment: I don't think so...I don't see anything added like that.